# pause() in TweenMax is not working

Tags: javascript, gsap

New to GSAP here. I'm trying to pause my animation when I click a button, but for some reason I can't pause the animation when my variable is referencing to a `TweenMax.staggerFrom` method. From what I understand, using the pause() method is as easy as attaching the method a variable referencing the tween. Any ideas why this is happening?

Relevant code below (I am using GSAP and jQuery)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    TweenMax.from("#from",5,{opacity:0,y:-200});
    var tween=TweenMax.staggerFrom(".square",3, {y:200, scale:0, backgroundColor:'#ff0000', delay:0.5},2);

    $("#pause").click(function(){
        tween.pause();
    });

});
```

The error I'm getting from the console is `Uncaught TypeError: tween.pause is not a function(…)`.

Relevant HTML

```
<style>
.square{
    width:110px;
    height:110px;
    background-color:#A58760;
    position:relative;
    margin:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    }
</style> 
<body> 
<div id="from" class="center"> <img src="the_lady_eve.jpg" alt="eve" width="500px"> 
</div> 
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<br>
<button id="pause"> Pause Squares </button>
<!--When I click this button, I pause the square animation. !-->

</body> 
<script src="GSAP_playPause.js"></script>
```

I notice I can pause `#from` when I use this code.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
var tween=TweenMax.from("#from",5,{opacity:0,y:-200});
    TweenMax.staggerFrom(".square",3, {y:200, scale:0, backgroundColor:'#ff0000', delay:0.5},2);
    $("#pause").click(function(){
        tween.pause();
    });

});
```

Comment: `staggerFrom`, `staggerFromTo`, `staggerTo` and I believe a few other static methods as well return an `Array` of tweens rather than a single tween. hence, `pause()` method is not available on an array. **[docs](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/staggerFrom/)**.

Comment: you can however use a `TimelineMax` instance and use it to further control the entire sequence of animation. **[example](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/fk89rf1j/)**.

Comment: Wait, is it the fact that `staggerFrom`'s target is an array the reason why `pause()` doesn't work, or is it because `staggerFrom` returns an array?

Comment: `pause()` doesn't work because `TweenMax.staggerFrom()` returns an array. On the other hand, `staggerFrom` on a `TimelineMax` instance returns the instance itself and hence `pause()` and other `TimelineMax` methods can be used on it. **[Link to TweenMax docs](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax)** and **[Link to TimelineMax docs](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax)**.

Answer (score 0):

use it like this

```
tween.paused( true );
```

https://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Core/Animation/paused/